# EF Core : separate Model and SQL attributes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I am new in EF Core (5), and read about the separation of concerns, so, as I understood, for EF there is need to put attributes (like, readonly, ColumnName, table name, etc) on the model entites...

Is there a way to configure all these attributes on `json` config or something like this in order do not mess the SQL Data information and the business model classes?

Say, I would like to create a class `User` but in the DB the table name would be `Utilisateurs`

Comment: You can use [FluentApi configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) to configure EF without polluting the Domain entities.

Comment: that it to configure in code. Is that possible to configure in a config file, do not have to recompile the solution if a change is needed?

Comment: You can, theoretically, create a JSON schema where you map EF configurations. On the .NET part, you read the JSON file, and based on the file properties you apply the specific EF configurations. However, I don't think it is possible to change the EF config without restarting the application. And, EF config are meant to be used as a "one-time" action. I don't think the approach with dynamic JSON configuration might be a good solution.

Comment: [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) explains all out-of-the-box methods for configuring the model (conventions, data annotations and fluent API). As you can see, there is no "json config or something like this", so what really is your question? :-/